# cassandra "invalid column name type"

Tags: cassandra, cql, cassandra-3.0, cqlsh

I'm running into an "Invalid column name type" error in Cassandra when copying data into a table. This data was extracted from the same table in a different Cassandra database.

```
cqlsh:test> COPY things (id,field1,field2,field3) from '~/code/things.csv';
```

Here's the response I get:

```
Using 7 child processes
Invalid column name type
```

What does this error mean? It doesn't seem to be anywhere on the internet.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Does your csv have a header with a `type` (reserved word) column? If so try editing it to be `things_type`